# need to add if statement to sql query to get different value

Tags: sql, if-statement, inner-join

I wrote a sql query to get max and min price for each ticket type, like below

```
select A.ticket_type,C.min_price, B.max_price 
     from ticket 
     as A inner join (select ticket_type, max(original_price) as max_price
     from ticket group by ticket_type) B 
     inner join (select ticket_type, min(original_price) 
     as min_price from ticket group by ticket_type) C 
     on A.ticket_type=B.ticket_type 
     AND B.ticket_type=C.ticket_type 
     AND A.original_price=B.max_price
```

Now, I need to add discount_price, discount_from and discount_to to this query. which means if today is between discount_from and discount_to, the price will get discount_price, otherwise will get the original_price, then the final result will print the max and min price of each ticket type. How to add this if statement in? Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: A, B and C are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, e.g. table alias T for the tickets table.

Comment: can explain more about the discount structure. Is the discount is maintained in the same table or do we have a separate table for that

Answer (score 1):

First I would not do inner joins just to find the min and max, you can use group by for that:

```
select T.ticket_type,min(T.original_price) min_price, max(T.original_price), mxn_price
 from ticket as T
 group by T.ticket_type
```

You can do an "IF" statement by using [CASE WHEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

In your case it would be something like this

```
select 
T.ticket_type,
min(T.original_price) min_price, 
max(T.original_price) max_price, 
CASE (WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN discount_from AND discount_to) 
THEN MIN(T.discount_price) 
ELSE MIN(T.original_price) END price
from ticket as T
group by T.ticket_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the additional fields are in table "ticket" this could work:

```
SELECT A.ticket_type, C.min_price, B.max_price 
FROM ticket A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ticket_type, 
               CASE WHEN ( discount_from <= CURDATE() AND CURDATE() <= discount_to ) 
                    THEN max(discount_price) 
                    ELSE max(original_price)
               END  AS max_price
               FROM ticket GROUP BY ticket_type) B 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ticket_type,
              CASE WHEN ( discount_from <= CURDATE() AND CURDATE() <= discount_to ) 
                    THEN min(discount_price) 
                    ELSE min(original_price)
               END  AS min_price
               FROM ticket GROUP BY ticket_type) C

ON       A.ticket_type = B.ticket_type 
     AND B.ticket_type = C.ticket_type 
     AND A.original_price = B.max_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are having a discount on a separate table and  `SQL SERVER`

```
WITH c1 AS (
SELECT ticket_type, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,discount_from,GETDATE())>-1
                          AND DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),discount_to)  >-1 THEN  discount_price 
                         ELSE original_price END AS original_price 
FROM ticket t 
JOIN discount d ON t.ticketType=d.ticketType
)
SELECT c1.ticket_type,MIN(original_price),MAX(original_price)
FROM c1
GROUP BY ticket_type
```

If you are using the same table remove the join :)